# How to set a TextView visibile in activity and not in CustomBroadcastReceiver class?

Tags: java, android, textview, broadcastreceiver

I have the following custom broadcast receiver class to check if wi-fi is connected:

```
public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private TextView textView;

    public NetworkStateReceiver(TextView textView) {
        this.textView = textView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (Network network : connectivityManager.getAllNetworks()) {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(network);
            if (networkInfo != null) {
                if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    boolean isWifiConnected = networkInfo.isConnected();
                    if (isWifiConnected) {
                        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm passing to the constructor a `TextView` object so it can be set visible if the the device is connected to wi-fi. In my MainActivity I'm creating an object like so:

```
CustomBroadcastReceiver receiver = new CustomBroadcastReceiver(textView);
```

The problem is that I don't want to make this operation on text view in this class, I want to make it in MainActivity class. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interface that contains a single method like `setIsConnected(Boolean)`

In `MainActivity`, implement this interface. The method will be called from your `BroadcastReceiver` and in this method you can do whatever you want with the UI.

Have the constructor of the `BroadcastReceiver` take the interface as a parameter instead of a `TextView`.

In `onReceive()`, call `setIsConnected()` on the interface with the boolean depending on the state of the WIFI.

Comment: Thank you for getting the time to answer my question. I'll try this and get you back.

Comment: It really worked. One more small question please. Do you think it makes any sense to use `LiveData` in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you would use `LiveData` for this. There are many different ways to solve such problems. What benefit would you get from using `LiveData`?

Comment: I think I'll get the same result but using this is more convenient. Btw, thanks a ton.